# Graphs whose minimal disconnecting sets have the same cardinality

Tags: graph-theory

Given a graph $G$, is there a nice characterization of graphs whose minimal (w.r.t. set inclusion) disconnecting sets† all have the same cardinality $\lambda$? If we call this property $P_\lambda$, then, from what I can tell, a simple graph is $P_1$ iff it is a disjoint union of trees, and $r$-regular simple graphs have the property $P_r$, but this is as much as I've been able to conclude.

†The terminology is Wilson's; just in case it isn't standard, I mean by ‘disconnecting set’ a set of edges of $G$ whose removal increases the number of connected components of $G$.

Comment: the triangle is $2$-regular but does not have the property $P_2$.

Comment: @dkuper: The triangle is not an exception as it cannot be disconnected by the removal of a single edge and the disconnecting set consisting of every edge is not minimal.